# MesosDNS with masters from different clusters

Tags: dns, mesos

Can MesosDNS serve dns requests for multiple mesos clusters? The goal is set the zone forwarder to that one instance of MesosDNS.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this would make sense (if it worked), because you could theoretically run the same service name in cluster 1 as in cluster 2 (e.g. `myapp.marathon.mesos`).

Normally IMO you'd setup Mesos DNS instances per cluster, and have a public slave running a load-balancer like `marathon-lb` as "router" to the services running in the cluster.

Comment: Right, assuming name conflicts is already taken care, I was just wondering if it would still work.

Comment: I guess it won't. And I really don't see a reason to so this. Can you elaborate why you think this would make sense instead of running Mesos DNS seperately?